# batch file run as admin registry key?

Tags: batch-file, registry, admin, registrykey

I was wondering if there is a string/value that I can add to the registry in order to always run a batch file as admin?

note: this batch file will run automatically at windows start up

This is only a project and I do not want to use any other language at this time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should have added instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

or

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the batch file can be changed to run as admin.

Comment: How? The batch file will be automated so the user will not be able to right click.

Comment: That restriction is not in your question.  FWIW you cannot get a batch file to run as admin in modern Windows without user interaction, as UAC has not yet been bypassed by any means.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was just wondering if there was anything I could add to the registry in order to run as admin without using any third party applications.

Comment: If there was a way to run as admin without the user knowing or manually authorising it, then malware could use it.  But UAC hasn't been bypassed yet.